# Defining structure variable after structure type

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct people 
{
    int id;
} person; // that part

int main()
{
    person = {3};   
    std::cout << person.id;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to ask you about initializing a structure (well, not initialization...creating structure type...I don't really know how do you call this). Once I've seen some keyword after structure, like the "person" here. All without any typedef.

I did a little research and found out that it's used to define a variable directly after the structure.

However, my code I posted above doesn't compile - it says syntax error, missing semicolon and crap like that meaning the expression is not valid.

What is this used for, and how to use this?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? And which compiler do you use?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012, syntax error '{', missing ';' before '{', expected an expression - everything in the first line of main().

Comment: Your code compiles without warnings and runs using `g++` compiler with `-std=c++0x` flag.

Comment: Why VS 2012 doesn't have c++11 compiler by default then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use the structure initialization syntax in a normal assignment, it has to be done when you declare your variable:

```
struct people 
{
    int id;
} person = { 3 };
```

If you have a C++11 compatible compiler, you can use the [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) syntax to *copy* later though:

```
person = people { 3 };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct people 
{
    int id;
} person; // that part
```

person is the global object of type `people`.

```
person = {3};
```

Is incorrect in C++03 and correct in C++11, since `{3}` will be treated like `people{3}`

Answer (score 1):

> Once I've seen some keyword after structure, like the "person" here.

It's not a keyword, it's a name. You're allowed to declare variables of a class type in the same statement that defines the type, if you like. It's equivalent to two separate declarations:

```
struct people 
{
    int id;
};
people person;
```

> However, my code I posted above doesn't compile

It sounds like either your compiler doesn't support C++11 (specifically, assignment from a braced list), or you're compiling with it disabled.

If you can't use C++11, then you'll have to assign each member separately:

```
// person = {3};   // C++11 only
person.id = 3;
```

or declare and initialise a local object and assign from that:

```
people temp = {3};
person = temp;
```

or initialise it in its declaration, rather than deferring until `main`:

```
struct people
{
    int id;
} person = {3};
```