# How do you call the optional instance of an object in a struct/class

Tags: c++

So in C++, you can create an instance of a particular struct/obj by adding the variable name after the declaration.

In the example below, we have a global instance of MyClass:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
  public:
  std::string get_name() const { return "HELLO"; }

} MyObject1;

MyClass MyObject2;

int main() {
  std::cout << MyObject1.get_name();
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a difference between MyObject1 and MyObject2 or are they exactly the same way to declare an instance and both just static global variables ?

Is there a name for this construct, where a type definition is also an instantiation?

Comment: Ehh, what? What's your actual question? It's rather unclear - could you elaborate? Also, could you add a [mcve] rather than just a code snippet?

Comment: Are you asking about the name of this syntax or how to use `MyObject` after it's declaration?

Comment: You just use `MyObject` directly (e.g., `MyObject(a, b)`, where `a` and `b` are some `shared_ptr<Animal>`). Example: https://ideone.com/4KJYQR

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining structure variable after structure type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057238/defining-structure-variable-after-structure-type)

Comment: The question seems clear to me.  "Is there a name for this construct, where a type definition is also an instantiation?"

Comment: This looks like old C-Style struct declaration.  In C++ struct is just a class that has default public members.  Interestingly, I think the C++ standard is that if something looks like a declaration then it is.. Here's a video on something similar. https://youtu.be/3MB2iiCkGxg?t=29m4s

Comment: @DrewDormann, thanks your wording is much better, I edited with your question

Comment: Okay, now that your question is much clearer, there is no difference at all between the declarations and definitions of `MyObject1` and `MyObject2`.

Comment: Voting to reopen.

Comment: Expanding on the comment from @Someprogrammerdude -- both declarations take on the form `{type} {variablename};`.  That's why they are the same.