# Why do we leave some structure variables out of the curly brackets?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand `struct` in C. I couldn't get the idea about this definition below. Why do we leave `aCard`, `deck[ ]` and `*cardPtr` out? What is the difference between including them in and leaving them out?

```
 struct card {
    char *face;
    char *suit;
 } aCard, deck[52], *cardPtr;
```

Comment: Think of it this way: the deck, per example is not the property of a card. A card can exist on its own without a deck. So the deck is not part of `card`.

Comment: It's just sloppy declaration style, combined with using "Linux style" structs instead of the more commonly used `typedef struct { } card_t;`... `card_t card;`

Comment: The code is hard to read, not intuitive, functionally correct but not as readable as how @MichaWiedenmann rewrite. Readable code is more important.

Comment: @Lundin Or even just `struct card { ... }` ... `struct card drawn;` (Which is what I prefer, but it's more a style thing)

Comment: consider: `struct human {face_t* face, torso_t* torso, arms_t* arms, legs_t* legs} Belverus;`. What's the difference between face/torso/arms/legs and Belverus?

Comment: @Lundin: There are [good reasons _not_ to typedef structs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4566358). It’s not “sloppy”; [Linux does it for a reason](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ - What does the name after the closing class bracket means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843145/c-what-does-the-name-after-the-closing-class-bracket-means) --- actually that is for c++ not c, but the syntax is inherited.

Comment: There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057238/defining-structure-variable-after-structure-type - but it's about a different problem.

Comment: @wchargin: read their comment again. Lundin said it is sloppy and typedef-free, not sloppy _because_ it is typedef free. In my opinion, what's sloppy here is the combined struct layout and variable declaration.

Comment: @wchargin If you read my comment again, you'll find that the sloppy part refers to the variable declarations and not the struct style. That being said, the Linux kernel style guide is an amateur-level document, completely without rationale or sources. Notably, the link offered provides no rationale, just opinions. And so the Linux kernel is about as far from canonical C as you can get, filled with reliance on poorly-defined behavior and non-standard extensions.  If you want serious coding guidelines for professionals, use MISRA or CERT.

Comment: You are not leaving nothing - struct followed by tag name and optionally followed by curly braces is part of the type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Though, this question has already answered, I am posting my answer because I think the OP has doubt in structure declaration and definition of variable of a structure type.

If you don't know what is a structure in C, please have a look at <sup>1)</sup> below.

The keyword *struct* introduces a structure declaration, which is a list of declarations **enclosed in braces**. An optional name called a structure tag may
follow the word *struct*. Hence, this is a structure declaration:

```
struct card {
    char *face;
    char *suit;
 };
```

here `face` and `suit` are **member variables**. Note that a structure declaration reserves no storage; it merely describes a template of a structure.

**A struct declaration defines a type.** The right brace that terminates the list of members may be followed by a list of variables. So, in your case:

```
....
} aCard, deck[52], *cardPtr;
```

`aCard`, `deck[52]` and `*cardPtr` are the **variables of type** `struct card`.

Since your structure declaration is tagged with name `card`, the tag `card` can be used later in definitions of instances of the structure. e.g. given the declaration of structure `card` above,

```
struct card someCard;
```

defines a variable `someCard` which is a structure of type `struct card`.

Alternatively, you can `typedef` a structure declaration and use it to define variables of its type.

---

1)

By definition - A structure is a collection of one or more variables, possibly of different types, grouped together under a single name.

As per C standard#6.2.5 [Types]:

> A structure type describes a sequentially allocated nonempty set of member objects (and, in certain circumstances, an incomplete array), each of which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct type.
>
> .....
>   .....
>   Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types. Array and structure types are collectively called aggregate types.46)

Comment: Or to put it in a nutshell, the whole "struct foo {...}" in the OP's code is just the same as int or float in "int i, j, k;" or "float x, y, z;".

Answer (score 74):

You are mixing things up. A `struct card` has the members `face` and `suit`. But there are three variables using the `struct card` type, namely `aCard, deck, cardPtr`.

Alternatively one could have written:

```
typedef struct {
    char *face;
    char *suit;
} Card;

Card aCard, deck[52], *cardPtr;
// or even
Card aCard;
Card deck[52];
Card *cardPtr;
```

For the `typedef` have a look at: [Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c) (It goes into the `typedef struct { ... } Foo;` vs `struct Foo {...}` debate).

Comment: Yes, the to-typedef or not-to-typedef debate rages on. But why introduce something that wan't present in the original question? It just complicates the answer. Sorry, but I'm downvoting for this reason, and upvoting [Jabberwocky's answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52851603/119527).

Answer (score 28):

Your piece of code could be written like this which makes it clearer:

```
struct card {          // define the struct card
    char *face;
    char *suit;
 };

struct card aCard;     // declare a variable "aCard" of type "struct card "
struct card deck[52]   // declare an array of 52 variables of type "struct card"
struct card *cardPtr;  // declare a variable "cardPtr" of type "pointer to struct card"
```

Answer (score 6):

A

```
struct card {
    char *face;
    char *suit;
 }
```

is just like `int`, but it is user defined, and

```
aCard, deck[52], *cardPtr;
```

are variable names, for example,

```
int aCard, deck[41], *cardPtr;
```

Comment: The `struct card` and `int` are indeed both types, but they are not equivalent.
I want to clarify this as I think this answer can be misread by some beginners or people not fluent in english.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared three variables. `aCard` is of type `struct card`, `deck` is of type `struct card[52]` and `cardPtr` is of type `struct card *`

Answer (score 0):

`aCard` and the rest you have mentioned are variables of type `struct card` and each of these variables contain `char *face` and `char *suit`. So how can some variable can contain itself i.e. `aCard` being inside the struct node.